# Neo4j not exists vs is null

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What's the difference between running

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT exists(n.foo) RETURN n
```

and

```
MATCH (f) WHERE f.foo IS NULL RETURN f
```

I ran both queries and got the same result, is the any difference in performance or something else?

Comment: `exists()` is a search, athough it will be short-circuited because `foo` is null. `IS NULL` is just a comparison.

Comment: Any idea which one should be faster?

Comment: A comparison, obviously, but I doubt you will be able to measure it if the obvious optimization is applied. It will be dominated by network tranmission time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's create a small example dataset:

```
CREATE (n1 {foo: 'bar'}), (n2)
```

We use [`PROFILE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) to show the execution plan and the number of rows in each step.

For query `MATCH (n) WHERE NOT exists(n.foo) RETURN n`:

[image]

For query `MATCH (f) WHERE f.foo IS NULL RETURN f`:

[image]

The execution plans show that the number of actual rows (traveling between the processing steps) and the number of database hits are the same. The filter conditions are a bit different, but I would not expect any significant differences - the execution time will likely to be dominated by disk access and, as EJP commented, by network transmission. Of course, to be sure, you would have to run a benchmark on a larger data set.

Comment: Beside the beautiful answer from @Gabor, according to this exists() is not supposed to be used for checking the existence of a property anymore but only for pattern existence. For checking property existence prefer n.property IS (NOT) NULL